# Cypress: Extract text and number from variable

Tags: cypress

we have an element on our booking page `".ItineraryDate [datetime]:last"` which displays the date of the last flight in the itinerary (e.g. `Tue 7 Jul`). For the purpose of a Cypress test, I need to extract the day (e.g. `7`) and the month (e.g. `Jul`).

```
cy.get(".ItineraryDate [datetime]:last").then($span => {
  const lastLegDate = $span.text()
})
```

This code creates const `Tue 7 Jul`, but I need to use only the day and the month. Do you know how could I extract it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cypress automatically includes moment.js and exposes it as Cypress.moment.

Refer [moment formats](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/)

You can extract the month and day in anyway you want using `Cypress.moment`.

**Markup**:

`<div class="date">Tue 7 Jul</div>`

**Test**:

```
cy.get('.date').then(($el) => {
    cy.log('original: ' + $el.text());
    const dateString = Cypress.moment($el.text(), 'ddd D MMM')
    const month = Cypress.moment(dateString, 'ddd D MMM').format('MMMM');
    const day = Cypress.moment(dateString, 'ddd D MMM').format('D');

    cy.log(`After formatting month = ${month}`);
    cy.log(`After formatting day = ${day}`);
    expect(month).to.equal('July');
    expect(day).to.equal('7');
});
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]